# Название месяца по номеру или номера по названию месяца

Tags: python, парсер, nlp, морфология

Мне нужно реализовать получение значения месяца в разных видах: номер, название в разных падежах, и с приставками (В январе).

Как это можно сделать?

Нужно что то в виде таблицы:

```
num, soon,      gen
1,   В январе,  января
2,   В феврале, февраля
```

Чтобы вызывать как то так:

```
> month(num=1).gen
> января

> month(gen='января').num
> 1

> month(soon='В феврале').gen
> февраля
```

Comment: в первом случае ещё понятно, но спойлер: всегда будет 'января'

Comment: приведите более обширный пример, из ваших данных мало что можно понять..

Comment: Храните в XML и читайте оттуда либо создайте класс, который будет выдавать нужное значение. Реализовать то что вы хотите можно написав нужный код.

Comment: @becouse гениально

Comment: `Как это можно сделать?` - [pymorphy2](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), например. Второй пример - привести к исходной форме, по ней в словаре (dict) найти номер месяца.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так, как в вопросе реализовать на чистом питоне не выйдет, но накидал это:

```
class Month:
    def gen(num):
        months = {1:'Январь', 2:'Февраль', 3:'Март', 4:'Апрель', 5:'Май', 6:'Июнь', 7:'Июль', 8:'Август', 9:'Сентябрь', 10:'Октябрь', 11:'Ноябрь', 12:'Декабрь'}
        print(months[num])
    def soon(num):
        months = {1:'В январе', 2:'В феврале', 3:'В марте', 4:'В апреле', 5:'В мае', 6:'В июне', 7:'В июле', 8:'В августе', 9:'В сентябре', 10:'В октябре', 11:'В ноябре', 12:'В декабре'}
        print(months[num])
    def num(gen):
        months = {'Январь':1, 'Февраль':2, 'Март':3, 'Апрель':4, 'Май':5, 'Июнь':6, 'Июль':7, 'Август':8, 'Сентябрь':9, 'Октябрь':10, 'Ноябрь':11, 'Декабрь':12}
        print(months[gen])
eval(input())
```

Вызывается при инпуте примерно так:

```
Month.num('Январь')
```

А аутпут в этом случае:

```
2
```

Или:

```
Month.soon(2)
```

Аутпут:

```
В феврале
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте использовать модуль [pymorphy2](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html):

```
from pymorphy2 import MorphAnalyzer   #  pip install pymorphy2

morph = MorphAnalyzer()

MONTHS = [
 'январь',
 'февраль',
 'март',
 'апрель',
 'май',
 'июнь',
 'июль',
 'август',
 'сентябрь',
 'октябрь',
 'ноябрь',
 'декабрь']

def get_month_num(month, morph=MorphAnalyzer()):
    mapping = {mon:n for n, mon in enumerate(MONTHS, 1)}
    month_norm = morph.parse(month)[0].normal_form
    return mapping.get(month_norm)

def get_month_name(month):
    if isinstance(month, int) and 1<= month <= 12:
        return MONTHS[month-1]
    return None

def get_month_soon(month, morph=MorphAnalyzer()):
    if isinstance(month, int) and 1<= month <= 12:
        month = MONTHS[month-1]
    p = morph.parse(month)[0]
    if p:
        loct = p.inflect({"loct"})
    if loct and p.normal_form in MONTHS:
        return f"в {loct[0]}"
    return None

def get_month_gen(month, morph=MorphAnalyzer()):
    if isinstance(month, int) and 1<= month <= 12:
        month = MONTHS[month-1]
    p = morph.parse(month)[0]
    if p:
        gent = p.inflect({"gent"})
    if gent and p.normal_form in MONTHS:
        return gent[0]
    return None
```

---

тесты:

```
In [46]: get_month_num("НоЯбрЕ")
Out[46]: 11

In [47]: get_month_num("января")
Out[47]: 1

In [48]: get_month_num("декабри")
Out[48]: 12

In [49]: get_month_num("мартобря")

In [50]: get_month_soon("НоЯбрЬ")
Out[50]: 'в ноябре'

In [51]: get_month_soon("января")
Out[51]: 'в январе'

In [52]: get_month_soon("февралю")
Out[52]: 'в феврале'

In [53]: get_month_soon("слово")

In [54]: get_month_gen("ОКТЯБРЬ")
Out[54]: 'октября'

In [55]: get_month_gen("сентябрем")
Out[55]: 'сентября'
```

---

```
In [63]: for i in range(1, 13):
    ...:     print("{}\t{:<10}\t{:12}\t{}".format(i, get_month_name(i), get_month_soon(i), get_month_gen(i)))
    ...:
    ...:
1       январь          в январе        января
2       февраль         в феврале       февраля
3       март            в марте         марта
4       апрель          в апреле        апреля
5       май             в мае           мая
6       июнь            в июне          июня
7       июль            в июле          июля
8       август          в августе       августа
9       сентябрь        в сентябре      сентября
10      октябрь         в октябре       октября
11      ноябрь          в ноябре        ноября
12      декабрь         в декабре       декабря
```