# Как перевести "последнее воскресенье марта" в конкретную дату?

Tags: дата, libre-office, libre-office-calc

Использую LibreOffice Calc. В таблице встречаются строки типа: "последнее воскресенье сентября" или "первая суббота марта".

Есть ли возможность перевести эти строки в конкретные даты?

Пример: "первая суббота марта" конвертируется в "06.03.21".

Comment: если бы год был, то можно поискать.

Comment: год текущий т.е. 2021

Comment: сделать вид типа "первая суббота марта 2021" не проблема, а вот остальное как? Даже не знаю в какую сторону копать!

Comment: вам можно в личной функции `basic` или встроенную функцию?

Comment: скорее всего, нужно сначала всё завести в цифровом виде. (0 / 1 ; 0..6 ; 0..11). Потом из этих кодов функция напишет словами и после выведет точную дату.

Comment: направление работы понял, буду думать

Answer (score 2):

Это интересная задача, но ее решение - достаточно трудоемкий процесс, поэтому предлагаю разбить ее на части (блоки):

1. парсинг строк, чтобы получать следующие кортежи после парсинга (на самом деле эту задачу лучше разбить на еще меньшие блоки и парсить отдельно номер, день недели и месяц в трех "подблоках"):

   - `"первая суббота марта"` -> `(1, 6, 3)`
   - `"последнее воскресенье сентября"` -> `(-1, 7, 9)`
2. создать объект типа `datetime` из компонентов, полученных ранее
3. воспользоваться решением, [подобным этому](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12796484/5741205)

PS самым сложным блоком - будет парсинг строк.

PPS [пример преобразования имени месяца в разных падежах в его порядковый номер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1063958/211923)

---

Дальше все просто - пытаетесь создать отдельно все блоки по отдельности и в конце связать все месте. Если у вас возникнут трудности с каким-то блоком - задавайте новые вопросы здесь. ;)